# How to typeset this such that they look symmetrical?

Tags: typography, brackets, subscripts

I am trying to type

```
$$\left|\uparrow\right\rangle_A{}_A\left\langle\uparrow\right|$$
```

But the As in the subscript are not symmetrical. One is upper and another is lower. Is there a way to type this more elegantly?

Comment: Unrelated, but `\[...\]` is preferred over `$$`: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/107497

Comment: Why not just use `\rangle_{AA}`?

Comment: @md2perpe sometimes I would need them separately with some other stuff between. In such case the asymmetrical typesetting looks weird

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way is to use `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` from `mathtools` package (an extension of `amsmath`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\ket}{\lvert}{\rangle}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\bra}{\langle}{\rvert}

\begin{document}
\[
\left|\uparrow\right\rangle_A{}_A\left\langle\uparrow\right|
\]

\[
\ket{\uparrow}_{A} {}_{A}\bra{\uparrow}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Edit

For fractions or tall expressions as [leftaroundabout](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5905/leftaroundabout) said in the comments, `mathtools` provides two options: An optional parameter `\ket[size command]{something}` and a starred version `\ket*{something}` that is preceded by `\left` and `\right` so they "grow" to match the content inside.

There are more additions to de delimiters, for example `\DeclarePairedDelimiterX` to be able to use arguments in the definition, as a `\newcommand`. Some examples from the [manual](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathtools):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\ket}{\lvert}{\rangle}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\bra}{\langle}{\rvert}
\DeclarePairedDelimiterX\braket[3]{\langle}{\rangle}%
 {#1\,\delimsize\vert\,\mathopen{}#2\,\delimsize\vert\,\mathopen{}#3}

\begin{document}
\[
  \bra[\Big]{\frac{a}{b}}, \quad \ket*{\frac{a}{b}}, \quad \braket*{B}{\sum_{k} f_k}{C}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

For the subindex in this taller delimiters it is still needed `\prescript` as in leftaroundabout answer.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks!

Comment: Nice, except that the names are exactly backward from the same constructions provided by the `braket` package.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Whoops! My bad, I didn’t remember how is Dirac notation. In a minute I will do the correction. Thanks for pointing that mistake

Comment: Can this be made to work also with tall expressions in the bra/kets? E.g. `\ket{\frac{\uparrow}{\downarrow}}_{A}` doesn't scale the delimiters like `\left| ... \right\rangle` would.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Thanks for pointing that out. I have edited the answer to cover your comments

Comment: Ok. But, as I see it `\DeclarePairedDelimiter`, albeit useful for other reasons, doesn't really do anything about the subscript alignment at all, right? Your original solution doesn't really do more than `\left|\uparrow\right\rangle{}_A{}_A\left\langle\uparrow\right|` in that regard.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
```

<sup><sub><sup><sub>%</sub></sup></sub></sup> I would use `\prescript`:

```
\[
  \left|\uparrow\right\rangle_A\prescript{}{A}{\left\langle\uparrow\right|}
\]
```

[image: low kets]

<sup><sub><sup><sub>%</sub></sup></sub></sup> Note that this also works when the kets get taller:

```
\[
  \left|\frac{\uparrow}{\downarrow}\right\rangle_A
   \prescript{}{A}{\left\langle\frac{\uparrow}{\downarrow}\right|}
\]
```

[image: tall kets]

<sup><sub><sup><sub>%</sub></sup></sub></sup> Shame about the (lack of) kerning. We might hack it to be a bit more snug with some manual spacing adjustments:

```
\[
  \left|\frac{\uparrow}{\downarrow}\right\rangle_{\!\!A}
   \: \prescript{}{A}{\!\left\langle\frac{\uparrow}{\downarrow}\right|}
\]
```

[image: with hacked kerning]

```
\end{document}
```